# cannot update GridPane.rowIndex from javafx scene builder

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I am unable to edit the GridPane.rowIndex from Javafx Scene builder. But if I manually edit the fxml file, it is properly parsed and picked by the scene builder. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

```
<GridPane alignment="CENTER" hgap="10.0" prefHeight="-1.0" vgap="10.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="org.ktest.study.javafx.FXMLExampleController">
  <!-- TODO Add Nodes -->
  <Text text="Welcome" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
  <columnConstraints>
    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" minWidth="10.0" />
  </columnConstraints>
  <padding>
    <Insets bottom="10.0" left="25.0" right="25.0" top="25.0" />
  </padding>
  <rowConstraints>
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" vgrow="ALWAYS" />
  </rowConstraints>
  <Label text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.rowIndex="2" GridPane.vgrow="ALWAYS" />
</GridPane>
```

**UPDATE:**
Actually I found that you can select the grid pane and select add row/column. But I still find the behavior strange.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a bug, because I remember doing it through scene builder. Though, I will accept the fact that scene builder do behaves strange sometimes. But then, we must give the application some time, its still in development phase and has a long way to go ! :)

-AA

Comment: Actually I found that you can select the grid pane and select add row/column.